# Unittest with command-line arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, argparse

From what I understand from another SO post, to unittest a script that takes command line arguments through argparse, I should do something like the code below, giving sys.argv[0] as arg.

```
import unittest
import match_loc

class test_method_main(unittest.TestCase):

    loc = match_loc.main()
    self.assertEqual(loc, [4])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[1] = 'aaaac'
    sys.argv[2] = 'ac'
    unittest.main(sys.argv[0])
```

This returns the error:

```
usage: test_match_loc.py [-h] text patterns [patterns ...]
test_match_loc.py: error: the following arguments are required: text, patterns
```

I would like to understand what is going on here deeper. I understand

`if __name__ == '__main__': 
main()`

says that if this is being executed by the 'main', highest level, default interpreter, to just automatically run the 'main' method. I'm assuming

`if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()`

just happens to be the way you say this for running unittest scripts.

I understand when any script is run, it automatically has an `argv` object, a vector collecting all the items on the command line.

But I do not understand what `unittest.main(sys.arg[0])` would do. What does 'unittest.main' do with arguments? How can I pre-set the values of sys.argv - doesn't it automatically reset every time you run a script? Furthermore, where does this object 'sys.argv' exist, if outside of any script? Finally, what is the correct way to implement tests of command-line arguments?

I am sorry if my questions are vague and misguided. I would like to understand all the components relevant here so I can actually understand what I am doing.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Without knowin more about how you are using `argparse` in `test_match_loc.py` it's hard to help you.  You may need to set `sys.argv` in that module, or call `parse_args` with a custom list of strings, as illustrated in many of the `argparse` documentation examples.  Also look at `argparse`'s own unittest file.

Answer (score 0):

Just by playing around with a pair of simple files, I find that modifying `sys.argv` in the body of the caller module affects the `sys.argv` that the imported module sees:

```
import sys
sys.argv[1] = 'aaaac'
sys.argv[2] = 'ac'
class test_method_main(unittest.TestCase):
   ...
```

But modifying `sys.argv` in the `main` block as you do, does not show up in the imported one.   We could dig into the documentation (and code) to see exactly why, but I think it's enough to just identify what works.

Here's what I reconstructed from your previous question of the imported module - with a few diagnostic prints

```
import argparse
import sys
def main():
    print(sys.argv)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description='Takes a series of patterns as fasta files'
            ' or strings and a text as fasta file or string and'
            ' returns the match locations by constructing a trie.')
    parser.add_argument('text')
    parser.add_argument('patterns', nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
    return 1
```

You could also test a parser with your own list of strings, recognising that `parse_args` uses `sys.argv[1:]` if its argument is missing or None:

```
def main(argv=None):
    print(argv)
    ...
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    print(args)
    return 1

loc = match_loc.main(['abc','ab'])  # and in the caller
```

Even though I was able to construct a working test case, you really should have given enough information that I didn't need to guess or dig around.

Comment: hi , I wanted to use same functionality.but getting IndexError: list assignment index out of range error while adding  params in sys args.

Comment: @Vish, check the size of `sys.argv` before trying to add items.

Comment: yes ..one more thing if somebody want to add extra param ,it can be added like sys.argv.append("ert")