# How to test Python classes that depend on argparse?

Tags: python, argparse, pytest

The below paste contains relevant snippets from three separate Python files. The first is a script called from the command line which instantiates CIPuller given certain arguments. What happens is that the script gets called with something like:
`script.py ci` (other args to be swallowed by argparse).

The second is part of a subclass called `Puller`. The third is part of a subclass of `Puller` called `CIPuller`.

This works wonderfully, as the correct subclass is called, and any user using the wrong other args gets to see the correct args for their given subclass, plus the generic arguments from the superclass. (Although I was made aware offline that perhaps I should use [argparse sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) for this.)

I'm stuck trying to write tests for these classes. Currently, I need an `ArgumentParser` to instantiate the classes, but in testing I'm not instantiating things from the command line, hence my `ArgumentParser` is useless.

I tried creating an `ArgumentParser` in the test harness to pass to `CIPuller's` constructor in the test code, but if I use `add_argument` there, argparse understandably complains about double (duplicate) arguments when it calls `add_argument` in the `CIPuller` constructor.

What would be a suitable design to test these classes with arguments?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                             

from ci_puller import CIPuller                                                    
import argparse                                                                   
import sys                                                                        

# Using sys.argv[1] for the argument here, as we don't want to pass that onto     
# the subclasses, which should receive a vanilla ArgumentParser                   
puller_type = sys.argv.pop(1)                                                     

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(                                                 
    description='Throw data into Elasticsearch.'                                  
)                                                                                 

if puller_type == 'ci':                                                           
    puller = CIPuller(parser, 'single')                                         
else:                                                                             
    raise ValueError("First parameter must be a supported puller. Exiting.")      

puller.run()                                                                      


class Puller(object):                                                             

    def __init__(self, parser, insert_type):                                      
        self.add_arguments(parser)                                                
        self.args = parser.parse_args()                                           

        self.insert_type = insert_type                                            

    def add_arguments(self,parser):
        parser.add_argument(                                                      
            "-d", "--debug",                                                      
            help="print debug info to stdout",                                    
            action="store_true"                                                   
        )                                                                         

        parser.add_argument(                                                      
            "--dontsend",                                                         
            help="don't actually send anything to Elasticsearch",                 
            action="store_true"                                                   
        )                                                                         

        parser.add_argument(                                                      
            "--host",                                                             
            help="override the default host that the data is sent to",            
            action='store',                                                       
            default='kibana.munged.tld'                                     
        )                             

class CIPuller(Puller):                                                           

    def __init__(self, parser, insert_type):                                      
        self.add_arguments(parser)

        self.index_prefix = "code"                                                
        self.doc_type = "cirun"                                                   

        self.build_url = ""                                                       
        self.json_url = ""                                                        
        self.result = []                                                          

        super(CIPuller, self).__init__(parser, insert_type)                       

    def add_arguments(self, parser):                                              
        parser.add_argument(                                                      
            '--buildnumber',                                                      
            help='CI build number',                                               
            action='store',                                                       
            required=True                                                         
        )                                                                         

        parser.add_argument(                                                      
            '--testtype',                                                         
            help='Job type per CI e.g. minitest / feature',                       
            choices=['minitest', 'feature'],                                      
            required=True                                                         
        )                                                                         

        parser.add_argument(                                                      
            '--app',                                                              
            help='App e.g. sapi / stats',                                         
            choices=['sapi', 'stats'],                                            
            required=True                                                         
        )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unittesting for `argparse` is tricky.  There is a `test/test_argparse.py` file that is run as part of the overall Python unittest.  But it has a complicated custom testing harness to handle most cases.

There are three basic issues, 1) calling `parse_args` with test values, 2) testing the resulting args, 3) testing for errors.

Testing the resulting `args` is relatively easy.  And the `argparse.Namespace` class has simple `__eq__` method so you can test one namespace against another.

There are two ways of testing inputs.  One is to modify the `sys.argv`.  Initially `sys.argv` has strings meant for the tester.

```
self.args = parser.parse_args()
```

tests `sys.argv[1:]` as a default.  So if you change `sys.argv` you can test  custom values.

But you can also give `parse_args` a custom list.  The `argparse` docs uses this in most of its examples.

```
self.args = parser.parse_args(argv=myargv)
```

If `myarg` is `None` it uses `sys.argv[1:]`.  Otherwise it uses that custom list.

Testing errors requires either a custom `parse.error` method (see docs) or wrapping the `parse_args` in a `try/except` block that can catch a `sys.exit` exception.

[How do you write tests for the argparse portion of a python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160078/how-do-you-write-tests-for-the-argparse-portion-of-a-python-module)

[python unittest for argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697502/python-unittest-for-argparse)

[Argparse unit tests: Suppress the help message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651705/argparse-unit-tests-suppress-the-help-message)

[Unittest with command-line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569245/unittest-with-command-line-arguments)

[Using unittest to test argparse - exit errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028204/using-unittest-to-test-argparse-exit-errors)

Comment: Modifying `sys.argv` for the test seems the easiest. Which is a more common practise, though, to modify `sys.argv` or to monkeypatch `ArgumentParser` to use your custom `arvg` by default?

Comment: Give `Puller` a separate `parse` method that takes an optional `argv` parameter that is passed to `parse_args`.  Then you can use it in normal run mode, or with test values.  `test_argparse` tests both approaches.

Comment: That was really helpful, even though I'd been over some of the links mentioned, the basic idea of setting sys.argv hadn't occurred to me. Sometimes we don't see the forest for the trees. :)